# I'm not getting the correct return value on the final return

Tags: c

Here's my problem. I'm not getting the correct char* return value in my code. Here are parts of my code

main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
....
....
    while (counter < line_C){
        char* zzz = searcher(line_arr[counter], 0);
        prog_counter[prog_counter_C] = atoi(zzz);
        prog_counter_C++;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

zzz gets the correct pointer, but the value seems to be overwritten.
Here's more code snippets to show the runtime on searcher function.

```
char* searcher(char input[], int method){
    ...
    ...
    else if (strncmp(instruction,"ADD", 3) == 0)
        return ADD(passer, method, 0);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Code snippet for add function:

```
char* ADD(char input[], int method, int bytecount){
    switch(method){
    case 0:
        char wtf[2];
        char *returner = itoa(Parse_Prog_Count(input), wtf, 10);
        return returner;
        break;
}
```

Code snippet for Parse_Prog_Count function:

```
int Parse_Prog_Count(char input[]){
    ...
    ...
    return bytecount;
}
```

I did try to debug, I'm getting the correct return value from Parse_Prog_Count, then ADD, but when it goes to the last return from searcher back to main, the value is wrong.

I also did try to catch the value from ADD to searcher first to check the value, and the return value is still correct. It's the final pass I'm having problem with.
the value from zzz seems to be changed.

Comment: You sure the var's not going out of scope? (Returning address of a stack-allocated var is a possible mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring wtf as a local variable on the stack, scoped to the ADD function:

```
char* ADD(char input[], int method, int bytecount){
    switch(method){
    case 0:
        char wtf[2];
        char *returner = itoa(Parse_Prog_Count(input), wtf, 10);
        return returner;
        break;
}
```

You are then returning a pointer to that stack memory in "*returner",  When the function exits, and goes out of scope, so does your data. So, your pointer is now pointing to who-knows-what.

Comment: ahhh, Thanks for pointing that out. Silly mistake on my part. The return value was working before but it went haywire when I added a new function below char* ADD.